# Change file-settings so multiple users can open at the same time

Tags: excel

I have an excel template that multiple users should be able to open and insert values into. I want user #2 to be able to open this file at the same time as user #1 is actively working in it. Both users should however use "Save as ---" to create a new file i.e. the template should not be edited but remain the same.

Currently, when user #1 has the file open and is working on it, user #2 is met with the message "File is locked for editing by user #1. Open Read only". How can I change the file settings to make it possible for several users to open it and work with it at the same time?

Comment: If that is template file then user 2 can copy and then edit.

Comment: That locking is how Excel works. **It's not a multiuser enviroment**. If somebody opens a file, it gets locked so next users will have a message prompted like the one you said.

Comment: "excel template that multiple users should be able to open and insert values into." --> should implement -->  "excel template that multiple users can copy n save as b4 using it.."